# Data modeling suggestions for Django app

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Django` app where users leave comments for each other. I'm now going to add a photo feature. I need some help in formulating the data model(s) for this photo feature.

Under this feature, users will be able to upload photos in a common area of the website, where the said photos will appear most-recent first. This is simple enough, so let's now add two complications to the feature:

> 1) For each photo entry, uploaders will have the option of including
>   additional photos (as a stream). The first photo will then be treated
>   as a cover photo that is shown in the common area of the website. Upon
>   clicking this cover, the entire stream will become visible.
>
> 2) For each photo entry, any viewer will be able to *reply* with a
>   photo of their own. If that happens, the two photos will be put
>   together as a stream, with the reply treated as a cover photo, to
>   appear in the common area of the website. Clicking this cover photo
>   will show both entries one after the other, thus showing the users
>   what the original photo was, and what the reply to it was.

How should I model the above requirements? I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Something like:

```
class PhotoReply(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)

class Photo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_stream = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image = models.ForeignKey(upload_to=upload_photo_to_location, storage=OverwriteStorage())
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    stream_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_reply = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reply = models.ForeignKey(PhotoReply, blank=True, null=True)
```

But there are obvious weakness, inconsistencies in that. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I understand you correctly that every photo can become a "cover photo", as soon as a user replies to it with another photo? If that's the case, then you only need to keep track of the "children" that a photo has, to know if you want to display it as "cover" or not.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', db_index=True, null=True, default=None)
    child_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(upload_to=loc)
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

So a photo that has `> 0` children is a "cover". And for each "cover" photo "x" you just need to look to look up all photos that have "x" as a parent.

Comment: Looks about right. I'm going to try it and get back to you.